# Python - API to Train custom voice using MS Azure

Tags: python, api, machine-learning, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am evaluating Microsoft Custom Voice using Azure AI and want to know how to programmatically create and train custom voices through API .I'm looking for creating a voice, uploading audio to it, and triggering the training job programmatically.

There's a documentation page on Microsoft site but that doesn't fulfil my criterial.
Please find below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-voice-create-voice

Comment: Actually, you can capture all APIs on custom voice portal in your browser

Comment: Stanley, How can we do that? can you please tell in detail.

Comment: Ok, this is something hacking, but I think it could be helpful for your development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture all APIs in a browser, for instance, using chrome, we create a project in a voice portal, press F12 to open the console, and monitor the network:
[image]
Let's create a new project, and see the request network package, you can see all API request details so that you can try this in your code :

[image]
[image]

Basically, you can use this way to find all APIs you need.

Comment: Thank Stanley. Let me try this.  Actually i'm very new to development and i needed this for my  project work . 
also are you there on Linkedin?

Comment: @KumarS，welcome, I not use Linkedin, if you have any questions, just @me here and let me know the question link. If my post is helpful, pls click the checkmark beside my answer to accept it :)

Comment: can you help/guide me in completing end-to-end task?

Comment: @KumarS, I am glad to, could you pls post another question with the details and let me know the question link?

Comment: Please find the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596536/train-custom-voice-using-azure-ai

Comment: any luck with the link ?

Comment: @KumarS, yep, I saw it, per my understanding, you are looking for an API set to create and train a custom voice model, I am a little bit busy recently, I think I can post my 
findings to you next week

Comment: Sure will wait until then.